# ESXi license expired and broke my ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, boot

I got my own ESXi server hosted at Hetzner, with some webpages etc.

I was unable to access the sites, so I went into the ESXi mangement panel and can see that all my VMs were offline and I got a notice that my free ESXi license was expired..

I have assigned a new license, but my Ubuntu install won't boot anymore.. My pfSense router/firewall and windows VM's work fine after they have been restarted.

When I boot I get this
[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu install booting]

Any way to fix this or move the data stored to a new Ubuntu VM?

I have tried booting with advanced and picking some of the recovery options, but get stuck the same place.

Comment: `My system won't boot. It says "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY". What should I do?` - Quoted from our [guide to writing good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) : *"People are going to look at you like you are illiterate, because the system told you what to do, and they will tell you to **run `fsck`** like your system said."*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> fsck /dev/mapper/webserver--vg-root

and reboot

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)